# django sweetalert2 activite when the data Inserted succesfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I read this https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django documentation about sweetify, and i did everything say in the documentation.but everytime the user admin Insert new data, the sweetify didnt activate, did i miss something? I already install it. I am using django 2.2.4

I have this code in my html

```
{% load sweetify %}
{% sweetify %}
    <form method="POST" action-xhr="/InsertProduct/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ....
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this is my views.py

```py
import sweetify
def InsertProduct(request):
    ....
    insert_data = Product(
       ....
    )
    sweetify.success(request, 'You did it', text='Good job! You successfully showed a SweetAlert message', persistent='Hell yeah')
    insert_data.save()
    
    return redirect('/') # <-- tabbed this line
```

sweetify.py

```
from sweetify.templatetags import sweetify
    
sweetify.DEFAULT_OPTS = {
    'showConfirmButton': False,
    'timer': 2500,
    'allowOutsideClick': True,
    'confirmButtonText': 'OK',
}
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    'sweetify',
]
SWEETIFY_SWEETALERT_LIBRARY = 'sweetalert2'
```

Comment: Is `return redirect('/')` untabbed in your actual code?

Comment: I saw this return redirect('/') from the documentation.

Comment: You don't have it tabbed to be inside the function, though

Comment: what should i replace?

Comment: Ill make the edit

Comment: thanks mr@Uuuuuumm

Comment: Does your actual code have the return statement tabbed correctly?

Comment: when i insert data, the page didnt reload but the data is save in my database, yes , i think it works, the sweetify didnt activate though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219619/discussion-between-justin-and-uuuuuumm).

Comment: Ive also tried the "" return render(request, "with the same html") "" it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much effort, the problem is a lack of scripts in the HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9">
</script>
```

The library needs these to actually display the alerts.
No backend errors will be thrown if this is not present